# Go to Definition and Find References not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-16.04

I'm interested in **[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com)**, the new editor Microsoft released a year and a half ago. If I can get the hang of it, I think I'll switch to it on my Ubuntu. So I've done a `"Hello, World!"` program trying to find how to configure and use VSC's features.

I've seen on VSC's site and on some videos how to configure a folder so that you could go to definitions and find references, but it nonetheless doesn't seem to work for me. I don't know if I've done something wrong or if it's a bug on VSC's part.

[Here is what my folder looks like](https://github.com/AnthonyD973/VSCode_NoIndexing). I've basically set up the `tasks.json`, `launcher.json` and `c_cpp_properties.json` files with default setup (compiling and debugging work just fine), but as you can see in the screenshot below, no indexing seems to be taking place since no symbol is found in `main.cpp` (even if I add new functions). Also, trying to find references of the `i` variable leads to `No results`, and asking to find `i`'s definition doesn't do anything.

I've already tried :

- Reinstalling VSC
- Removing plugins
- Adding the `${workspaceRoot}` folder in the `c_cpp_properties.json`'s include for Linux

Here's the screenshot. Notice my installed extensions on the left.

[image]

Nothing I've seen has helped me understand what the problem is. Have I done something wrong? I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several binaries of the Microsoft C/C++ vscode extension for Linux are 64-bit. Therefore, if you're on 32-bit Linux, some of the cpptools functionality won't work. You can check the [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/424).

Answer (score 0):

I work also with Microsofts plugin C/C++ in a quite big C project. The C symbol references works good. Maybe you can try to add your projects root directory to "includePath" in c_cpp_properties.json.

But I am pretty sure, that local variables of functions are not parsed.

Comment: I just tried, and that didn't work. Even trying to peek at the definition of `iostream` does nothing. Strange...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe does the C++ intellisense plugin conflict with the Microsoft C++ plugin. can you disable the plugin provided by Austin
? The Clang plugin is also not necessary. The Microsoft plugin has Clang support and code completion integrated.

Comment: I've tried disabling and restarting the app, as well as uninstalling the plugins and then restarting the app (apart from the C/C++ plugin of course), but still no luck. I guess it's a VSC bug. Though it's strange, since tutorials like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UpN9zyNXOjY) show that it's supposed to work for Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

When I asked my question, I was on an Ubuntu VM. Yesterday, I installed an Ubuntu partition on my HDD, and vscode worked perfectly, with peek definition, find references etc.

After a few hours, I ended up in the same situation as when I made my post. But then I just closed and reopened VSCode, and it worked again. Definitely a VSCode bug.

EDIT : Seems to be the same issue as [this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/59).